# How to get values from all arguments

Tags: r

I would like to create an edited version of the `paste()` function. However, I'm not sure how to deal with the `...` argument in the original function and how to get all values.

Original function:

`paste(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE)`

I would like to have something like this:

`MYpaste(..., sep = "", collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE)`

which would be defined in the following way

```
MYpaste <- function(..., sep = "", collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE) {
  x <- as.list(...)
  x <- x[x != ""]
  paste(x, sep = sep, collapse = collapse)
}
```

In case `...` is, e.g., a vector, this works ok. The problem is when `...` are multiple objects:

```
> MYpaste(c("", "b", "a", ""), collapse = " + ")
[1] "b + a" # this is ok
> MYpaste(c("", "b", "a", ""), sep = " + ")
[1] "b" "a" # this is ok
> MYpaste("", "b", "a", "", collapse = " + ")
[1] "" # this should be "b a"
> MYpaste("", "b", "a", "", sep = " + ")
character(0) # this should be "b + a"
```

Apparently, `MYpaste()` gets only the first object and ignores all other objects.

Comment: What would `MYpaste(c(,"g", "", "b"), "a", c("w","x", "y","z"), sep = " + ")` return?

Comment: There is an empty argument, but without that it would return `[1] "g + a + w" "b + a + x" "g + a + y" "b + a + z"`

Comment: this is wrong use of `paste`. `paste('b', 'a', collapse=' + ')` cannot return `b + a`. this is because `b` and `a` are elements of 2 different vectors thus `sep` takes precedence over `collapse`.  in short the first example cannot be the same asthe 3rd example.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have:

```r
MYpaste <- function(..., sep = " ", collapse = NULL, recycle0 = FALSE) {
  x <- lapply(Filter(\(x)any(nzchar(x)), list(...)), \(x)x[nzchar(x)])
  do.call(paste, c(x, sep=sep, collapse=collapse))
}


MYpaste(c("", "b", "a", ""), collapse = " + ")
#> [1] "b + a"
MYpaste(c("", "b", "a", ""), sep = " + ")
#> [1] "b" "a"
MYpaste("", "b", "a", "", collapse = " + ")
#> [1] "b a"
MYpaste("", "b", "a", "", sep = " + ")
#> [1] "b + a"
```

Comment: Great, this works excellently. Please, could you comment `lapply` part? Why does my function not take all objects, while yours does?

Comment: @Adela when you have 2 vectors ie `c("", "a", "")` and `c("", "b", "")` , these are stored in a list. And you have to traverse the list removing all empty strings. thats the use of lapply.